# addEventListener ENTER_FRAME

Tags: actionscript-3

when I try to make a addEventListener I get an error:
Line 20 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

```
package player {
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Stream {
        private var _Sound = null;
        private var _Channel = null;

        function Stream(){
            this._Sound = new Sound();
        }

        public function play(url){
            this._Sound.load(new URLRequest(url));
            this._Channel = this._Sound.play();

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.myFunction);
        }

        private function myFunction(e:Event){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: make your Stream class extend EventDispatcher and import flash.events.EventDispatcher

Comment: You don't need to use all the "this." prefixes here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import flash.events.Event;` goes at the top under `package player {`.

You need to import the event before using it.

**Update:**

```
package player {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Stream extends Sprite {
        private var _Sound = null;
        private var _Channel = null;

        public function Stream(){
            this._Sound = new Sound();
        }

        public function play(url){
            this._Sound.load(new URLRequest(url));
            this._Channel = this._Sound.play();

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.myFunction);
        }

        private function myFunction(e:Event){

        }
    }
}
```

Use this code. Generally, you want to add an `ENTER_FRAME` event to a display object. The `Sprite` class is a display object. I'm making it a `Sprite` by using the `extends` keyword. Please note that you need to import the class you're extending, as I've done.

Comment: thanks! :) actually I tried to extend with the Sprite, but I forgot to import the class

Comment: btw. how can I pass arguments to myFunction with addEventListener?

Comment: You can't pass arguments directly through a listener. In order to do so, you'd have to create your own event class that extends `Event` and make a variable there.

Comment: it would be better to extend EventDispatcher rather than Sprite, which comes with a lot of useless overhead since the class isn't a Sprite.

Comment: You can try as3 signals instead of events in order to pass arguments more easily  https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

Answer (score 0):

The instruction:

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.myFunction);
uses this to self-reference the player instance, but this.myFunction is redundant since myFunction is already a method belonging to the player instance.

Instead use:
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);

Comment: now I get this: Line 18 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type player:Stream. I have added import flash.events.Event; in the top